# How install and use another version python(python 2.7) on linux with the default python version is python 2.6

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

There is a default python version, namely python 2.6, on the GPU server with Linux OS. Now I want to install a new python version on the server from its source, namely python 2.7. I should not change the default python version since I am not the administrator and some reason. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can install your new version of Python. It should be accessible with the `python27` command (which may be a symbolic link).
Then you will just have to check that the `python` symbolic link still points to `python26`.

Doing this, `python` will keep on execute Python 2.6 while `python27` will execute Python 2.7

Comment: I do not have the right to make a symbolic link since I'm not the administrator. Even I do so, how can I use pip to install packages for my python not for the default python?

Comment: if your Python version is not provided with pip, you will have to install it for your new Python version. This can be done by simply installing it using the new Python version. Then you will have to use this specific version of pip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `virtualenv`, to execute your programm in an environment with python 2.7.

Install `virtualenv` and [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (for comfotable use.)

`mkvirtualenv -p <your-python-version>` would then start a virtual environment where the desired python version is the default.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Tryph's answer, you can install that new version to your home directory, then in a directory specified within your PATH (like in .bash_profile), you can point to that directory and within there create a sym-link that points to the new python.

For instance, if you have a bin folder in your home directory that is specified in the path

ln -s /bin/python ~/bin/python